# Choosing the correct pattern

Tags: php, design-patterns

I have about 10 different APIs. which have absolutely different response structure (all of them are in XML format). **But all of them contain information about photos, tags etc, but in different format.** So, I' planning to create separate class for each API and this class will implement interface. For example.:

```
class XmlApiName implements IParseable {
    public function requestApi() {}
    public function getPhotos() {}
    public function getTags() {}
}
```

Beside this 10 classes I should have one main class to operate with them. Frankly speaking, it looks like `Zend_Cache` with choosing `Zend_Cache_Backend` interface implemented classes for storing cache. As far as I remember this pattern is called `Strategy`, but how can I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/Patterns.aspx. This site describes the GOF design patterns and gives code examples (though the .Net examples aren't always really optimised).

Strategy pattern is near the end of the page.